# Use the van der Corput Lemma to prove the equidistribution of $\{\alpha n^2\}$

Tags: ergodic-theory

The van der Corput Lemma states

> **Van der Corput Lemma:** Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence in a Hilbert space $H$. Define a sequence $(s_n)$ by
>   $$s_h = \limsup_{N \to \infty} \left | \frac1N \sum_{n = 1}^N \langle x_{n + h}, x_h \rangle \right |.$$
>   If there now holds that
>   $$\lim_{H \to \infty} \frac1H \sum_{h = 0}^{H - 1} s_h = 0,$$
>   then we have that
>   $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left \| \frac1N \sum_{n = 1}^N x_n \right \| = 0.$$

We should be able to prove using this lemma that ($\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$) $\{n^2 \alpha \}$ is equidistributed where $\alpha$ is irrational.

Does someone have a *hint* how to do this? If I solve it I will modify my question to give the full solution. I assume that I am missing something simple.

Comment: Don't forget to use Weyl's criterion.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Take $\displaystyle x_n (t) = e^{2\pi i n^2 \alpha t}$ in $L^2(S^1)$.

Comment: Okay, I have fixed the typos. What is your Hilbert space? $L^2$? Then what is the variable because $\alpha$ is a fixed irrational number?

Comment: Typo-day today :) I think now the hint's fine.

Comment: Okay, I have picked this up again. I'm not sure what norm you have on your space, for me $L^2(S^1)$ has the norm $\|f\| = \left (\int_0^1 f(e^{2 \pi i \theta}) \, d\theta \right )^\frac12$. This norm does not make any sense in this case and replacing $f(e^{2 \pi i t})$ with $f(t)$ does not seem to give me an interesting conclusion. I'm really missing something I think. Say it is the norm with $f(t)$, then I have $L^2$ convergence and from that I can conclude nothing pointwise except for a subsequence. Could you extend your hint a little bit?

Comment: @Jonas: I'll think about it again and post something. But please be a bit patient, I'm pretty busy these days. Sorry if my suggestion didn't seem to help.

Comment: Okay, thanks :). I'm not in a hurry.

Comment: I think I've got it but with a different Hilbert space but with the same function. I'll see if I'll add it as a cw answer.

Comment: @Jonas: Well, I feel that accept was rather undeserved. Could you tell me what the Hilbert space is, since I haven't yet figured it out (my notes on that contain a really stupid mistake that make the whole argument nonsensical).